# Getting 7 rows of text is name "App.Model.Folder" when using hub?

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I don't have enough to upload a photos.

Here xaml:

```
<HubSection MinWidth="865" MaxWidth="865" Header="effort english">
<DataTemplate>
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
   <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
   <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="40">
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid Grid.Column="0">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Text="Filter by unit :" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
         <ComboBox x:Name="combunit" SelectionChanged="combunit_SelectionChanged" Loaded="combunit_Loaded" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource comboviewunit}}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding title}">
         </ComboBox>
      </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here additional on xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
   </CollectionViewSource>
   <CollectionViewSource x:Name="comboviewunit"></CollectionViewSource>
</Page.Resources>
```

Here code in class:

```cs
class MainFolder
{
    List<Folder> folder;
    public object query_unit()
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"Model/XMLEffort.xml");
        List<Folder> data = (from q in xml.Elements("effort").Elements("English")
                           group q by q.Element("foder").Value into g
                           select new Folder
                           {
                               title = (string)g.Key,                                 
                           }).ToList();
        return data;
    }
```

Here folder class

```cs
public class Folder
{
    public string title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

THat result is 17 rows of text is name "App.Model.Folder".(link images:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/641506)

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayMemberPath` in your case should be simply the property name, not a binding statement :

```
<ComboBox ..... DisplayMemberPath="title">
```